# Absolute inequality: What are the sufficient conditions under which $(a - (a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x))x < 0$?

Tags: inequality

What are the sufficient conditions under which the following inequality is satisfied: $(a - (a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x))x < 0$, where $a>0$ and $b>0$?

This is what I tried:

- If $x>0$, then:

  $a - (a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x)<0$

  $a < a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x \leq |a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x|$

  $a < \sqrt{a^2 + (b^2 - a^2)}$, since $|c\cos x + d\sin x|\leq \sqrt{c^2+d^2}$

  $\frac{a}{b} < 1$.

I think I've got it right until this point.

- If $x<0$, then:

  $- a + (a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x)<0$

  $- a < - (a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x) \leq |a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x|$

  $- a < \sqrt{a^2 + (b^2-a^2)}$

  $- a < b $

  $\frac{a}{b}>-1$

Thus, to guarantee that $(a - (a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x))x < 0$, $\forall x$, then $|\frac{a}{b}| < 1$? Is it right? Is there a more elegant and/or succint derivation?

**Edit**: $(a, b, x)$ are all real numbers.

Comment: You are going backwards there. In the first case, you want to have $\dfrac{a}{b}<1$ implies your desired inequality, but you did it in reverse. If they do happen to be equivalent, then you need to prove that too.

Comment: Thank you, I've just noticed that $a<|a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x|$ does not imply $a<a\cos x + \sqrt{b^2-a^2}\sin x$ necessarily. Actually, it was a clear mistake... I've managed to solve my problem by using the polar transformation $a\cos x + b\sin x = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos (x-\tan^{-1}(b/a))$.